# Unexpected Output: not getting the exact output

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to run this code but I am getting four outputs instead of two:

```python
class Computer:
    def config(self):
        print("i5 16 1TB")
        
comp1=Computer()    
comp2=Computer()

print(Computer.config(comp1))
print(Computer.config(comp2))
```

Output:

```
i5 16 1TB
None
i5 16 1TB
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `print()` if your method doesn't return anything since `None` returned by default.

```
class Computer: 
    def config(self): 
        print("i5 16 1TB")

comp1=Computer()
comp2=Computer()

comp1.config()
comp2.config()
```

Comment: Why the odd way of calling an instance method? Why not just call `comp1.config()` and `comp2.config()`?

Comment: Thanks, @JustinEzequiel, I just pointed to avoid the use of `print()` for the function returning `None` and missed that part. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use return in  function

```
class Computer:                  
    def config(self):            
        return "i5 16 1TB"       
                                 
comp1=Computer()                 
comp2=Computer()                 
                                 
print(Computer.config(comp1))    
print(Computer.config(comp2))
```

Every function in Python returns something. If the function doesn’t have any return statement, then it returns None.

Comment: `print(comp1.config())`.